# How can I read colored rows of an xlsx file via python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

**Data:**

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9 
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
```

**Here is colored data**

[image]

How can I read colored rows of an xlsx file via python?

The output I wanna see:

```
 4  5  6
10 11 12
```

Comment: How did you make the colours in the xlsx file? Can you share your xlsx file (or perhaps a similar template)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlrd but only support xls format. When you use this code you will see   [these indexed numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y8JF.png) [from that kind of format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwTgV.png) and you can check these index from [IndexColor Class page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.indexedcolors?view=openxml-2.8.1)

```
import xlrd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('color_codes.xls', formatting_info=True)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
bgcol=np.zeros([sheet.nrows,sheet.ncols])
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        c = sheet.cell(row, col)
        cif = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
        iif = wb.xf_list[cif]
        cbg = iif.background.pattern_colour_index
        bgcol[row,col] = cbg
        colormask=pd.DataFrame(bgcol)
print(colormask)
```